# Erlang - Network connection between different network

Tags: erlang

I have a problem, because I am amator in Erlang. I look for an example or any explanation communication between different network. All of examples concern communication in LAN or within range one computer.

Could any help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check out this FAQ first: http://www.erlang.org/faq/problems.html#id54626 ("9.8  Why won't my distributed Erlang nodes communicate?")

Comment: I had some tips for someone else on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668743/dstributed-erlang-networking-echo-server/19671858#19671858